# Detecting the URL POST parameters to pass

Tags: html, screen-scraping, wikimapia

The problem is to screen-scrape the latitude/longitudes for entities(restaurant-names, etc.) from wikimapia.org AND restrict the results based on the latitude/longitude

Here is how I tried:

1. Install Live HTTP Headers addon in Firefox.
2. Filled up the form on the main-page of wikimapia.org to "pizza corner"
3. Saw that the the main site would hit the URL - "http://wikimapia.org/sys/search4/?q=pizza+corner" and then I screen-scraped the results from this page.
   However I am not able to restrict the results based on the latitude/longitude

While I try to pass the parameters lat/long (given as x & y in the Live HTTP Header add-on), the results are not restricted unlike the main-site.

For eg: I hit the URL - http://wikimapia.org/sys/search4/?x=775833000&y=129832000&z=3&q=pizza%2520corner&start=0&jtype=&try=0 the results are not restricted to India.

Am I sending the wrong parameters?
What are the correct latitude/longitude parameters for the URL - http://wikimapia.org/sys/search4/? so that I can restrict the results as the wikimapia site.

Thanks in advance.
ps: Sorry for the verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sending any POST parameters. Yours are GET parameters.

POST data appears in the body of the request, not in the URI.

Comment: Edited. Thanks.  What I really, meant to say was that the URL that I was using to scrape, possibly passes them as POST characters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the lat/lon being represented as X and Y in the URL. I'm seeing the following:

```
http://wikimapia.org/
  #lat=33.8704156
  &lon=-84.375
  &z=3
  &l=0
  &m=a
  &v=2
  &search=pizza+corner
```

Comment: The URL that I am using to scrape is "http://wikimapia.org/sys/search4/?q=pizza+corner" - this is also used by the above URL you posted - which, is not possible to scrape.